# Is it safe to use magnetic Qi wireless chargers with the iPhone 8 or iPhone X?

Tags: iphone, charging

There are a number of Qi wireless chargers that are advertised for the iPhone 8 and iPhone X that hold the phone on by a magnet. From what I have heard, Apple said that any Qi wireless charger will work with iPhone 8 and iPhone X. Is there any official guidance regarding whether or not the magnetic Qi wireless chargers could harm the iPhone. Because there has been none, I am led to believe that it is safe to use.

Is there (official or otherwise) reason to believe that magnetic Qi chargers could harm iPhone 8 or iPhone X?

---

Example: [Magnetic QI Wireless Charger Phone Holder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075TZL737)

Screenshot in case link dies: 
[image]

Comment: Check out the reviews. 1.0 out of 5 stars Weak magnet
Kristin October 25, 2017 - Verified Purchase
"The magnet isn’t strong enough to hold my iPhone 8 plus at any angle. This is without a case and it didn’t come with any magnets that you attach to your phone. I tried my iPhone 6 with this to see if the magnet on the charger would at least hold the smaller phone and it barely holds it. If you were to use this in your car with a smaller iPhone in any position other then horizontal, any bump or sudden stop would cause the phone to fall off the charger."   - I wouldn't recommend that one

Comment: @MelvinJefferson, great point. I just grabbed a search result for example from Amazon. A higher priced one would probably be better.

Comment: But to answer your question it should charge with no problem. It'll be a slow charge but thats better than no charge. Although buying a battery pack that supports IQ technology (Anker & RavPower) will perform better, unless you need the stand for GPS.

Comment: My concern would be if you magnetize any ferrous metals that happen to be in the phone, you'll reduce the sensitivity of the magnetometer/compass. I can see this in theory, but I don't know what real effects this would be.